# Internet Explorer confused after scrollTop set in select listbox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html-select

The following has been tested in Internet Explorer 8 on Windows XP, Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 and Chrome 17 on Windows 7.  It works properly in Chrome, but not IE.

Briefly, IE seems to get confused when the scrollTop property of an HTML select object (listbox).  After setting it, IE puts the scroll box at the correct place and displays the correct values for that scrollTop value.  However, clicking on the scrollbar after setting scrollTop, jumps the display to somewhere else in the list.

Does anyone know how to get IE to honor the value of scrollTop, such that the end user scrolling will start from that scrollTop position?

I don't do a lot of javascript programming, so please be gentle. :)

If you run this, input a value between 0 and the maximum scrollTop, press the Go To scrollTop button and then press the up or down arrow on the scrollbar.  When it works, you will inch up or down from where the scrollTop button brought you.  When it doesn't work, you'll slide all the way back to the top of the list, or a random distance from where you were if you already manually scrolled before pressing the button.

Here is the code online: http://jsfiddle.net/davidd/2yPVa/

Here is the code inline:

```
<html>
<form id="myForm">
<select name='ListBox' id='LB1' size=10></select><BR>
Set scrollTop Value: <input type="text" id="scrollTopValue" value="1000" onkeypress="return noenter()"/>
<br><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="updateNumbers()">Update Numbers</button>
<button type="button" onclick="goToScrollTop()">Go To scrollTop</button>
<br><br><br>
<select name='ListBox' id='LB2' size=10" ></select><BR>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = initialize();

function initialize() {
    var i;
    var select1 = document.getElementById( 'LB1' );

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    {       
        try
        {
            select1.add(new Option(i));
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
            select1.add(new Option(i),select1.options[null]); // for older IE versions
        }   
    }
    updateNumbers();
}

function goToScrollTop() {
    var select1 = document.getElementById('LB1');
    var input1 = document.getElementById('scrollTopValue');

    if (input1.value < 0 || input1.value > (select1.scrollHeight - select1.clientHeight) || isNaN(input1.value))
    {
        alert("scrollTop value must be between 0 and " + (select1.scrollHeight - select1.clientHeight));
    }
    else
    {
        select1.scrollTop = input1.value;
    }
}


function updateNumbers() {
    var select1 = document.getElementById( 'LB1' );
    var select2 = document.getElementById( 'LB2' );

    select2.length = 0;
    try
    {
        select2.options.add(new Option('scrollTop = ' + select1.scrollTop));
        select2.options.add(new Option('scrollHeight = ' + select1.scrollHeight));
        select2.options.add(new Option('clientHeight = ' + select1.clientHeight));
        select2.options.add(new Option('scrollHeight - clientHeight = max scrollTop = ' + (select1.scrollHeight - select1.clientHeight)));

        select2.options.add(new Option('listbox.length = ' + select1.length));
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        alert(ex);
    }
}

function noenter() {
  return !(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13); }

</script>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @david, Have you got this to work? I just have the same issue...